# How to put items into their own seperate string when they are in a list

Tags: python, list

I've tried searching from an answer to this but couldn't find one specific to my problem. I have a list of lists and I want everything inside of the lists of lists to be in their own separate string. This way I could access each item individually. My list looks something like this:

> [['milk, water, apple, orange'], ['tomatoes, carrots']]

And I am trying to get it to look like this:

> [['milk', 'water', 'apple', 'orange'], ['tomatoes', 'carrots']]

(I got to this senario after I imported a file by executing the folllowing code. It puts the items in a list of lists but dosen't put the objects into their own strings, which is the problem I am trying to fix.)

> with open(file, 'r') as f:
>
> > ```
> > Main_list = [line.split() for line in f]
> > ```

Comment: The fact that you even have a list that looks like `['milk, water, apple, orange']` is usually a sign that you did something wrong to get to this point, and you should adjust that code rather than trying to fix things in post-processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your list is actually

```
x = [['milk, water, apple, orange'], ['tomatoes, carrots']]
```

you can use List Comprehension

```
[a[0].split(", ") for a in x]
[['milk', 'water', 'apple', 'orange'], ['tomatoes', 'carrots']]
```

Comment: Despite the unjustified downvotes, I'm keeping the answer because it is what OP asked for. :)

Comment: Except it isn't, quite.

Comment: How come it is not? Am i missing smth?

Comment: You're overlooking the spaces, for one thing.

Comment: Okay, so I believe it is better to close the question and not help then :) exactly what SO is meant for

Comment: Even after fixing the mistake in your answer, it doesn't seem like the most useful advice to me.